# Add a description on navigation drawer item

Tags: android

Im using [navigation drawer](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)
but I need items with a description behind the title [like this example](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7MFE5VE1TUF9HRGc/components_dialogs_simplemenus3.png).

Here is my item on the xml:

```
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_calculate"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_distance"
                android:title="@string/title_calculate" />
```

Can I set a custom layout for all the item? Using the prop `app:actionLayout` I can only change the 50% of the layout...

(I cant use external libraries, so I need to add the description with the xml)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this layout for custom navigation drawer.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<!--your custom views-->


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Using xml would give me less work but thanks! could be the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something called as `DrawerLayout`.

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

and in the layout file add

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/navigation_bar_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

The navigation_bar_layout file will now contain your design of the drawer.

Comment: Could be the solution but I need to change everything and create a listview and the adapter.. If there is no other solution... :(

Comment: There are libraries to achieve this. But your case is not reliable on library.